# How to change Max VSI limit via API?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

By default in IBM Cloud, users are limited to 20 VSIs but via ticket, this limit can be increased to what client needs. Is there an API for changing Max VSI limit?

Regards
Behzad

Answer (score 2):

The attribute to adjust the number of VSIs that can be deployed on an account is an internal attribute and not something that customers can adjust themselves. You will need to open a sales ticket to request the increase.